# ActionScript - MouseOut Event

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseover

I am trying to get a movie clip to play properly. The first part with MouseOver works fine, but the MouseOut doesn't get a response.

Here's the code:

```
stop();

callout_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, playCallout, false, 0, true);
callout_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, resetCallout, false, 0, true);

function playCallout(evt:MouseEvent):void {
trace("Moused Over Callout Button");
play();
}
function resetCallout(evt:MouseEvent):void {
trace("Mouse has moved off button");
gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: the code looks fine... strange...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe since you are using weak references (the 3rd parameter), the object is garbagecollected before the MOUSE_OUT.

Comment: What do you recommend as a solution?

Comment: leaving out the last parameter; or setting it to false (it's the same)

callout_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, playCallout, false, 0);

Comment: err i picked the wrong one to example:

callout_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, resetCallout);

btw since the last three parameters are the default ones, you can skip them.

Comment: Hi. It is still not working. I will post it on Monday so you can see and then hopefully I can get it fixed. Thanks.